# Highcharts datetime line travels backwards with unsorted data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know I should have sorted data, but I'm getting it from different API calls and there are 10 other reasons why I cannot have sorted data.

I have some unsorted data, that I need to plot in a timeseries graph.

```
{
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 2), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 6), 106.4],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 3), 129.2],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 5), 144.0],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 8), 176.0]
        ]
    }]

}
```

When I use the above options for highcharts, the line travels backwards
[image]

Is there a way I can make highcharts do the required sorting, and plot the chart correctly?
I have tried `dataSorting` option as well, but it didn't work.

Highcharts has a `dataSorting` flag to sort the data, so its not completely crazy of me to expect it.

Comment: I have not worked much with them but ideally, the answer should be no. As a charting library, its objective is to render charts and not sort data. Plus data should be sorted based on business's requirement and not in any default way

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the dataSorting property?

```
{
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        dataSorting: {
            enabled: true,
            sortKey: 'value'
        },
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 2), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 6), 106.4],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 3), 129.2],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 5), 144.0],
            [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 8), 176.0]
        ]
    }]

}
```

Comment: that sorts the data, but ruins the timestamps

Comment: Suggestions: If you are able to create a snippet or a fiddle, it will be wasier for everyone to check. As an answer, please add explanations and if you can, add reference links of docs or example so that readers can understand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts requires sorted data in ascending X order. You need to pre-sorts the data, for example:

```
var data = [
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1), 29.9],
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 2), 71.5],
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 6), 106.4],
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 3), 129.2],
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 5), 144.0],
    [Date.UTC(2020, 0, 8), 176.0]
];

data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        data
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cf8tq6a2/

Comment: yes, they do infact throw the warning/error, but they also have a `dataSort` key to sort the data, so I thought they might have something for datetime graphs as well.

Comment: Hi @Dushyant Bangal, Please check docs about data-sorting feature: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-sorting

Comment: yes, I've already seen that. Thats the built-in feature I mentioned in my comment and question. Theres no mention of `datetime`, and when I use it, it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, it does't work because the feature ignores initial `x` values and sets it's own by increasing `x` value from 0.